# Flask 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask

Hi I am trying to make the final project for CS50, I run command flask run and get a url, but get status 404 not found. I used very similar code for the last task on CS50 and it worked just fine. Please help. This is my code, and I do have all html files with correct paths.

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
import datetime

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///meals.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            flash("You must provide a username!")
            return render_template("login.html")

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            flash("You must provide a password!")
            return render_template("login.html")

         # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            flash("invalid username and/or password")
            return render_template("login.html")

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/homepage")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    # If method is POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        # Personal touch - Require users’ passwords to have some number of letters, numbers, and/or symbols
        password_symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '.', '_', '&']

        # Check if any fields are empty
        if not name:
            flash("You must provide a username!")
            return render_template("register.html")
        elif not password:
            flash("You must provide a password!")
            return render_template("register.html")
        elif not confirmation:
            flash("You must confirm tha password!")
            return render_template("register.html")

        # Require users’ passwords to be 8 char long and to have some number of letters, numbers, and/or symbols
        if len(password) < 8:
            flash("Password must be at least 8 characters long!")
            return render_template("register.html")

        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
            flash("Password must have at least one number!")
            return render_template("register.html")

        if not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
            flash("Password must have at least one uppercase!")
            return render_template("register.html")

        if not any(char in password_symbols for char in password):
            flash("must contain at least one symbol of following: ! # $ % . _ &")
            return render_template("register.html")

        # Check if password and confirmation match
        if not password == confirmation:
            flash("Password doesn't match", 400)
            return render_template("register.html")

        # Check if username is taken
        rows = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?", name)
        if len(rows) > 0:
            flash("Username is taken", 400)
            return render_template("register.html")

        # Add the new user into the database
        hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?,?)", name, hash)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        flash('Registered!')
        return redirect("/homepage")

    # If method is GET
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")

@app.route("/homepage")
def homepage():
    return render_template("homepage.html")
```

I am using VS code on cloud, just as for all others tasks in cs50, I run flask run and get a link with no error messages. Than I follow that url and instead of the page the browser returns 404 Not Found

Comment: It returns 404 not found for which url?

Comment: this is what that it generates when I run the command run flask:

INFO: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on https://kris-glitch-jubilant-computing-machine-qx4p496q46jcp45-5000.preview.app.github.dev
INFO: Press CTRL+C to quit
INFO:  * Restarting with stat
so when I follow the URL it responds:
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2022 18:07:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I fixed it!! For anyone having a similar issue, this was the problem. The homepage route should be only / like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template("homepage.html")
```